# What could be the problem with my microsoft Event code

Tags: php, laravel, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to create an event and return an event link using microsoft Graph, Laravel and Laravel Twill.
I am getting the error,

> Client error: `POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar/events` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` 
> response:
> {"error":{"code":"BadRequest","message":"Property start in payload has a value that does not match schema.","innerError":{"date":"2023-02-01T09:57:57","request-id":"3430668e-7bb5-46e1-8960-904f1e2d1521","client-request-id":"3430668e-7bb5-46e1-8960-904f1e2d1521"}}}

Below is my function

```
public function createMicrosoftMeeting($data)
 {
    $access_token = Cookie::get('access_tokenz');
     $graph = new Graph();
     $graph->setAccessToken($access_token);
     $start_time ='2023-04-15T12:00:00';
     $end_time = '2023-04-15T12:50:00';
     $event = new Event();
     $event->setSubject($data['title']['en']);
     $event->setBody(new ItemBody([
         'contentType' => ItemBody::CONTENT_TYPE_HTML,
         'content' => strip_tags($data['description']) 
     ]));
     $event->setStart($start_time);
     $event->setEnd($end_time);


 

     try {
         $calendar = $graph->createRequest("POST", "/me/calendar/events")
             ->attachBody($event)
             ->execute();
             
         return $calendar->getOnlineMeetingUrl();
     } catch (\Exception $e) {
         return $e->getMessage();
     }
 }
```

I have tried checking the datetime formats and below is  the microsoft Graph event instance with the payload

```
**Microsoft\Graph\Model\Event {#2155
  #_propDict: array:4 [
    "subject" => "sample test
"
    "body" => Microsoft\Graph\Model\ItemBody {#2139
      #_propDict: array:2 [
        "contentType" => "html"
        "content" => "In the instance is throws an error, check if the server space is full&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;df -hIf there is no space, clear out files that are no longer need in the /var/www/html directoryOnce done, check the server space again&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"
      ]
    }
    "start" => "2023-04-15T12:00:00"
    "end" =>   "2023-04-15T12:50:00";
       ]
}
```

Comment: Sounds like your date format doesn't match the expectation. I believe https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/datetimetimezone?view=graph-rest-1.0 documents the data type and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=php shows how to set the date with PHP when creating an event, using the `DateTimeTimeZone` class.

Comment: The problem is even when i put constant time formats as per the docs, i still get the same error

Comment: Strange...can you edit the question and show exactly how you're doing that as well? Just for clarity.

Comment: I have edited the question and added static start and end dates based off of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=php

Comment: The docs have it done using a wrapper class in the examples `$start = new DateTimeTimeZone();
$start->setDateTime('2017-04-15T12:00:00'); 
$start->setTimeZone('Pacific Standard Time');`. That's not quite the same as what you've done here.

Comment: So how can i use the DateTimeTimeZone() in Laravel?

Comment: Just like any other class. Is there a specific problem if you try to use the suggested code, e.g. `new DateTimeTimeZone();` etc? I don't know but I assume it's a class from the graph API SDK